# APYDataGridBundle: For aliased column data not displayed

Tags: symfony

I am using the APYDataGridBundle for Symfony2.

My final objective is to have one line per user in the grid (ok for now) and to have a favoris_id column with the id or null (then with JS I can manage to show if the contact is part of the user favorite or not with ajax to add or remove the favorite).

If I use annotations to add the column, I end with one line per existing favorite across users instead of 1 line with null or id for the logged-in user.

I am therefore manipulating the query to add a field and then adding an aliased column. The generated query is ok, the column si displayed but the cells are empty and they do not show f.id.

Here is my query:

```
$source->manipulateQuery(
            function ($query) use ($alias, $userId, $sourceType) {
                $query
                    ->addSelect('f.id favorisid')
                    ->leftJoin($alias . '.usersFavoris', 'f', 'WITH', 'f.user = :user')
                    ->andWhere($alias . '.source = :sourceparam')
                    ->setParameter('user', $userId)
                    ->setParameter('sourceparam', $sourceType)
                ;
            }
```

Here is my aliased column:

```
    // Add Column favoris_id
    $myCol = new TextColumn(
        array(  'id'            => 'favoris_id',
                'title'         => 'favoris id',
                'field'         => 'favorisid', // The aliased name
                'isManualField' => true, // Indicate it is a manual (or aliased) field
                'isAggregate'   => false, // Defaults to false, set true if using aggregate func. like SUM()
                'source'        => true, // Indicates the grid should retrieve it from the source (the query)
    ));
    $grid->addColumn($myCol,8);
```

Here is the relevant part of the contacts entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Curuba\contactsBundle\Entity\contactsFavoris", mappedBy="contact", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $usersFavoris;
```

The runnable query provided by the profiler is correct:

```
SELECT c0_.nom AS nom0, c0_.prenom AS prenom1, e1_.nom AS nom2, 
f2_.fonction AS fonction3, u3_.fullname AS fullname4, c0_.updated AS updated5, 
c0_.id AS id6, c0_.fullname AS fullname7, c0_.prefix AS prefix8, 
c0_.communications AS communications9, e1_.cp AS cp10, e1_.adresse AS adresse11, 
f2_.persomail AS persomail12, c4_.nom AS nom13, s5_.nom AS nom14, s6_.nom AS nom15, 
c7_.id AS id16
FROM contacts c0_
LEFT JOIN fonctions f2_ ON c0_.id = f2_.contact_id
LEFT JOIN entites e1_ ON f2_.entite_id = e1_.id
LEFT JOIN users u3_ ON c0_.referent_id = u3_.id
LEFT JOIN categories c4_ ON e1_.categorie_id = c4_.id
LEFT JOIN souscategories s5_ ON e1_.souscategorie_id = s5_.id
LEFT JOIN sources s6_ ON e1_.source_id = s6_.id
LEFT JOIN contactsFavoris c7_ ON c0_.id = c7_.contact_id AND (c7_.user_id = 59)
WHERE c0_.source_id = 1
ORDER BY c0_.fullname ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from one of the contributor of this bundle.
We have to use the same names even though there is a 'flied' parameter.
So using favorisid instead of favoris_id solves the issue:

```
// Add Column favoris_id
$myCol = new TextColumn(
    array(  'id'            => 'favorisid',
            'title'         => 'favorisid',
            'field'         => 'favorisid', // The aliased name
            'isManualField' => true, // Indicate it is a manual (or aliased) field
            'isAggregate'   => false, // Defaults to false, set true if using aggregate func. like SUM()
            'source'        => true, // Indicates the grid should retrieve it from the source (the query)
));
$grid->addColumn($myCol,8);
```